# GCP Api com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthIOException

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

Im trying to upload image on google drive. The API seems is verified. Since in GCP console I got

Verification Status
Verified
Your consent screen has been verified. If you make changes that require verification later, you must resubmit your application for review

But after uploading i have exception

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthIOException
```

And cause

```
com.google.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthException: NeedRemoteConsent
```

Full exception message
[image]

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue(error).
I'm using google drive API and facing the same error in the Android release build.

Comment: com.google.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthException: NeedRemoteConsent

anyone can help me out with this error I'm stuck with this in android

Answer (score 6):

Also faced the same error. When calling a Drive service, you should catch `UserRecoverableAuthIOException`, get the intent from it `UserRecoverableAuthIOException#getIntent()` and start the intent with `startActivityForResult` to show an OAuth2 permission page to user. Then handle a user's choice in `onActivityResult`.

```
try {
    // Some call to the Drive
} catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
    startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
}
```

You can test it by revoking a permission for your app in your Google Drive settings.